# Breadcrumb: change links depending on where I am

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I would like to know how I can do to change the links depending on where I am on my site?

For example, I would like that when I click on "Sign In", it is like this:

```
Forums > Sign In
```

http://prntscr.com/47d04a

[image]

container.php:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="breadcrumb_top">
            <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="forums">
                        <a href="index.php">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "index") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Forums</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "members") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Members</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "sign_up") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Sign Up</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "sign_in") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Sign In</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "change_theme") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Change Theme</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "contact_us") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Contact Us</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "help") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Help</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "rules") !== false) {
            echo "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 15px;'>Rules</h1>";
            /* Code here. */
        }
        ?>
        <div id="breadcrumb_bottom">
            <div class="breadcrumb_links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="forums">
                        <a href="index.php">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like that everything be automated depending on where I am. If I click on "Members" in the top_bar, I would like that "Forums" in the breadcrumb should be replaced by "Members", etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my pages I'll create some PHP variables or constants that describe what the page name, parent and title are and then use a function to determine what page I'm on by what's defined/set.

This is an idea of what it's like.

```
<?php

define('PARENT','Blog'); // the site section/parent
define('PAGE','Posts'); // the child page under the site section
$page_title = 'My Blog'; // the page's title


function active($str, $submenu='') {

    if(!defined(PARENT) || !defined(PAGE)) {
        return false;
    }

    if($submenu) {
        if($str == PARENT) {
            return ' visible';
        }
    } else {
        if($str == PARENT || $str == PAGE) {
            return ' class="active selected"';
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo $page_title;
?>

<ul class="submenu<?php echo active('Blog', 'submenu') ?>">
    <li<?php echo active('Posts') ?>>
        <a href="/blog/posts/">Posts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I still have trouble, can make it to make it directly compatible with my code, please?